# SQL refusing to do a join even when every identifier is valid? (ORA-00904)

Tags: sql, oracle

Made this account just to ask about this question after being unable to find/expending the local resources I have, so I come to you all.

I'm trying to join two tables - ORDERS and CUSTOMER - as per a question on my assignment

> 1. For every order, list the order number and order date along with the customer number, last name, and first name of the customer who placed the order.

So I'm looking for the order number, date, customer number, and the full name of customers.

The code goes as such

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDR_ORDER_NUMBER, ORDERS.ORDR_ORDER_DATE, ORDERS.ORDR_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER.CUST_LAST, CUSTOMER.CUST_FIRST
FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDERS.ORDR_CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.CUST_CUSTOMER_NUMBER;
```

I've done this code without the table identifiers, putting quotation marks around ORDERS.ORDR_CUSTOMER_NUMBER, aliases for the two tables, and even putting a space after ORDR_ in both SELECT & WHERE for laughs and nothing's working. All of them keep coming up with the error in the title (ORA-00904), saying [ORDERS.]ORDR_CUSTOMER_NUMBER is the invalid identifier even though it shouldn't be.

[Here also are the tables I'm working with, in case that context is needed for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3sGn.png).

Comment: Please post the DDL for the tables as text in your question, not as an image.

Comment: You don't have a JOIN in your SQL, so you're not trying to do a JOIN. *SQL is refusing* is not true; you've not asked for that JOIN to be done. You may want to go back over your course notes.

Comment: Also, hint: You should **never** have a comma in your `FROM` statement. If your teacher is saying that you should, find a new teacher or class.

Comment: @KenWhite that's patently untrue. Oracle still supports the old-style join syntax and the OP has definitely written a join. True, it's done in a way that's old-fashioned and arguably unclear and less self-documenting, but that doesn't make it wrong like you're implying it is. Saying the OP should never use old-style syntax is unproductive - there's plenty of existing SQL out there that uses it, so knowing about it is a good thing. I do advocate for the using the modern ANSI-style join syntax in general. but using the old-style isn't wrong.

Comment: @Fan_of_Simon_Pegg what do you get when you run the following query? Please edit the question to add in the results: `select table_name, column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name in ('ORDERS', 'CUSTOMER') order by table_name, column_id;`

Comment: @Boneist: I didn't say Oracle didn't support it. But it's been antiquated since 1992, and any instructor who is teaching it today is teaching such old concepts that they're probably not qualified to be teaching. `JOIN ... ON` has been in place since the `02` standard was released, and is what should be taught (and used) now. If I had a job applicant who came in and wrote `FROM xxx, yyy`, they wouldn't be hired. Since '92', a join has the word `JOIN` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, the query that produces the result you want should take the form:

```
select
  o.ordr_order_number,
  o.ordr_order_date,
  c.cust_customer_number,
  c.cust_last,
  c.cust_first
from orders o
join customer c on c.cust_customer_number = o.ordr_customer_number
```

As you see the query becomes a lot easier to read and write if you use modern join syntax, and if you use table aliases (`o` and `c`).

Answer (score -1):

You have to add JOIN or INNER JOIN to your query. Because the data comes from two different tables the WHERE clause will not select both.

`FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.order_Customer_Number = Customer.Cust_Customer_Number`

Comment: `where` clause is sufficient to perform `join`, because `inner join` is a subset (projection) of cartesian product of two sets (join partners). Although it is hard to read such joins compared to ANSI explicit `JOIN` keyword, Oracle uses then in their applications (OeBS, HCM)